# shopping-api module classes not found in shopping-web

Tags: liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-ide, liferay-service-builder, liferay-7.1

I have created liferay project using version`portal-7.1-ga3`. In web module, While trying to fetch list of Products and iterating that list in Web module ViewProductsMVCRenderCommand class, That time getting `javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/project/demo/model/Product`, In this point api `model classes` and `service classes` not accessible in web-module .

I have exported `model` as well as `service packages` in shopping-api `bnd.bnd` file and Imported those packages in `shopping-web` bnd.bnd file, I also tried to import those service builder generated modeles and services with `Import-Service` OSGi manifest headers, But still getting same error. Here is my project github repository link https://github.com/vishwa-np/demo.git. After adding `dependencies, package export and import`, **shopping-api** and  **shopping-service** module classes not finding in **shopping web module.**

```
Shopping-api bnd.bnd

Bundle-Name: shopping-api
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.project.demo.api
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package:\
    com.project.demo.exception,\
    com.project.demo.model,\
    com.project.demo.service.persistence,\
    com.project.demo.service

-check: EXPORTS
-includeresource: META-INF/service.xml=../shopping-service/service.xml
```

```
Shopping-service bnd.bnd

Bundle-Name: shopping-service
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.project.demo.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
Liferay-Service: true

Export-Package: \
    com.project.demo.service.*,\
    com.project.demo.model.impl.*
```

```
Shopping-web bnd.bnd

Bundle-Name: shopping-web
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.web.project.demo
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package: com.web.project.demo.constants

Import-Package: \
    !com.project.demo.exception.*,\
    !com.project.demo.model.*,\
    !com.project.demo.service.persistence.*,\
    !com.project.demo.service.*,\
    !com.project.demo.model.impl.*,\
    !com.project.demo.service.impl.*,\
    *

Import-Service: \
    !com.project.demo.exception.*,\
    !com.project.demo.model.*,\
    !com.project.demo.service.persistence.*,\
    !com.project.demo.service.*,\
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

In your shopping-web you are *explicitly forbidding* the imports (see the "!"):

```
Import-Package: \
    !com.pro...
```

I'd expect bnd to do the wiring for you if your dependencies are declared well, so you'd need *not a single explicit import* in bnd.bnd

When the module is generated for you, the wiring should be good. Or compare your code [with this sample](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/apps/service-builder/basic) (use the branch for your version)

Comment: Thank you, After removing complete import-package statement the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: is solved.